# Declaring an enum of a class inside a class as a static member

Tags: java, enums

Consider the following inner class:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    public E value;
    public Node<E> next;
    public Node<E> previous;

    public Node(final E value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (next != null);
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return (previous != null);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + value + ")";
    }
}
```

Is there an (intuitive) way to declare a `FAKE_HEAD` and a `FAKE_TAIL` variable?

I know I can add the following inside the class:

```
public static Node<E> FAKE_HEAD = new Node<>(null);
public static Node<E> FAKE_TAIL = new Node<>(null);
```

However, now I am attaching state to a member variable that should not have state, which I am a bit concerned with.

In practice when I get a `Node<E> node` and want to check if it is the fake head, then I will call `if (node == FAKE_HEAD)`.

I would like it to be an enum like:

```
public static enum Node<E> {
    FAKE_HEAD,
    FAKE_TAIL
}
```

Yet the enum should also be a `Node<E>`, as I want to be able to reference the `FAKE_HEAD` as a `Node<E>`.

How would I implement such design? Would creating a `Node<E>` interface and having an `class ImplementedNode<E> implements Node<E>` (better name wanted) class and `enum EnumNode<E> implements Node<E>` work?

Comment: I would just use the static fields but make them final. I think the enum approach will make it overly complicated. For instance if you introduce an interface then you probably will need to declare the node behaviours in it, and then the enum will have to implement the behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

> Would creating a Node interface and having an class ImplementedNode implements Node (better name wanted) class and enum EnumNode implements Node work?

Yes, and that is what I would do. I would name them `interface INode`, `class Node`, and `enum ENode`.